# How to make floating button movable android

Tags: android

Is it possible? I like to drag the floating button across the screen anywhere the user want. Like make the floating button movable. For example if the user wants it on the top - right , he will drag the button to the top-right of the screen.

I wonder if it's possible. If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can move views across the screen by setting its  x and y coordinates.
So, in your case, as you want to move floating button on the screen according to users inputs(Drag and drop), you have to get the coordinates of user touch on the screen using MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE action and set that coordinates to your button at the same time.

Try the following code:

```
 yourFloatingButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
         if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
             oldXvalue = me.getX();
             oldYvalue = me.getY();
             Log.i(myTag, "Action Down " + oldXvalue + "," + oldYvalue);
         }else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE  ){
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),(int)(me.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2)), (int)(me.getRawY() - (v.getHeight())));
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
         }
         return true;
     }
 });
```

Hope it helps you!